# Servlet: Image upload with content type as image/jpeg

Tags: java, image, servlets, file-upload, sapui5

I am using sapui5 control UploadCollection to upload set of images and servlet to process the post request.

**Problem 1**: I have slightest idea how to parse the content to get images in doPost.
**Problem 2:** For the UploadCollection, it's not advisable to change the content type by modifying the header parameters. So, i'd need to get those images in servlet without multipart as content type.

I have seen dozens of examples, all having multipart as content type. I need a solution where content type from browser comes as image/*. Hints or code snippets would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which examples you have seen. Normally the UploadCollection never uses multipart. You can check the code of the [UploadCollection here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/UploadCollection.js#L2778) and see that the FileUploaders are always built with `useMultipart: false`.

Also, if you check the examples from the Explored app, you will see that the content type is `image/png` or whatever type of file you select (on Chrome):

[image]

I am not really sure what is the behaviour on IE 8 / 9, where things are a little different (uploads through AJAX is not supported).

The multipart content type is controlled by the [useMultipart](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader.html#getUseMultipart) property of the FileUploader. If you need to play around with this value, you will need to replace the default upload button from the UploadCollection. To do this, simply make the default upload button invisible (using the `uploadButtonInvisible` property) and add your own FileUploader in the toolbar of the UploadCollection.

Related to the Servlet question: it depends what you want to do with the Image. [You can get the InputStream from the request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream())
 and then use it for whatever you need it. The input stream will contain the image itself (if the content is not multi-part that is).